# Why does it play the sound first?

Tags: python, audio

Well, I have those two functions in a class and in evento(self) I want it to play some sounds when something happens, in this case if someone wins or lose.

The problem is I want to delete "olafo" when that happens, before the sound playing but it plays the sound first and then deletes "olafo"

Also if there's a way to do both at the same time that would be better

```
def evento(self):
    for i in self.coorRed:
        redcros = self.canvas1.find_overlapping(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
        if self.olafo in redcros: #WIN
            self.canvas1.delete(self.olafo)
            sound = "Versus Win   New Super Mario Bros"
            self.beep(sound)

    for i in self.coorYellow: 
        yelcros = self.canvas1.find_overlapping(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
        if self.olafo in yelcros:#LOSE
            self.canvas1.delete(self.olafo)
            sound = "Lose Life   New Super Mario Bros"
            self.beep(sound)

    for i in self.coorRest:
        rescros = self.canvas1.find_overlapping(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
        if self.olafo in rescros:
            pass
```

by the way I'm using winsound if that's important or the problem, I need to use builtin librarys

Comment: How do you know that it is deleting out of order? Is it just that whatever is showing you that it is deleted is updated slowly?

Comment: @hazzey it plays first the sound and deletes olafo after it ended

Comment: You are going to have to provide your code that handles the deleting.

Comment: @hazzey is in there, the one that says self.canvas1.delete(self.olafo)  anyway I fixed it with PlaySound(sound, SND_ASYNC)